# Using an external Barcode Scanner with Android

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I have an `EditText` that I want to use an external barcode scanner with. I am having trouble getting the text from the `EditText`, because the barcode scanner sends the `Enter` signal, and not the Send or Done button in the soft keyboard. I have tried to tinker with `IME Options` and `OnKeyPressed` but I still cant figure it out.

Comment: Question is not clear. Post your code what you have tried

Comment: What type of external scanner are you using? Most scanners have an option to change which character, if any, is added to the end of the barcode